# Chandelier cord was cut off and sold to me

Tags: electrical

<s>Can I add 10’ of 18 gauge wire to 2’ of 16 gauge wire to make the cord longer?</s> It is only used for short term events like weddings.

I am sorry, I gave backwards info: the original cord is 18g and what I have on hand already is 16g. Can I add the 10 feet of additional 16g to the 2feet of 18 gauge that was cut off?

Comment: Is replacing the cord outright not an option?

Comment: Actually, can you open up the chandelier and take photos of how the wiring is spliced inside it?

Answer (score 1):

More important than the breaker protecting the circuit is the load on that cord.  If the chandelier had all led lamps the cord might handle the current, but since it was wired with 16ga I wouldn't use any smaller than that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the breaker protecting the circuit, no if it is less than 20 amps, but more importantly, why would you use 18 ga wire? Also a splice will require a legal mechanical component to be installed without access.